# Error : No module named 'psutil'

Tags: python, psutil

I've been trying to install `Peter Chervenski's MultiNEAT` and ran into a problem while running setup.py (`python setup.py build_ext`):

> File "c:/Users/1234/Documents/Alex/multineat/peter-ch-MultiNEAT-f631e2f/setup.py", line 7, in 
>       from site-packages import psutil'

And I made sure this module is installed: used `pip install` a couple of times and it said:

> Requirement already satisfied: psutil in
>   c:\users\1234\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages

And I checked this directory myself and found `psutil` module there (I even deleted it and reinstalled one more time). And after that, I still got the same error with `Python` not seeing `psutil`. Is there any way I can solve this problem? (I am using `Windows 10`, latest version of `Python`)

Comment: Are you missing an import statement in your script?

Comment: No, I am not missing it. I do have an import segment "import psutil".

Answer (score 19):

Error I got in windows 10 while executing a python script ->

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\YOUR NAME\Desktop\Sample.py", line 2, in 
>       import psutil
>
> ImportError: No module named psutil

This is how I resolved the issue ->

```
C:\python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

[Latest pip version got installed successfully]

```
C:\>python -m pip install psutil

Collecting psutil
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/6a/34525bc4e6e153bf6e849a4c4e936742b365f6819c0462cebfa4f082a3c4/psutil-5.4.7-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (220kB)
    100% |UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU| 225kB 696kB/s
Installing collected packages: psutil
Successfully installed psutil-5.4.7
```

Finally, Sample.py got executed successfully

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me..

```
sudo pip install --upgrade psutil
```

Answer (score 15):

**Follow these steps on windows:**

1. Open command prompt in **administrator mode**
2. Enter **Command** `python -m pip install psutil`
3. **Upgrade pip if outdated** `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

[Process Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkmXj.png)

Answer (score 7):

I solved a problem and if you had a similar problem you should try this:

1. upgrade `pip` to the latest version (`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`)
2. delete `psutil` (`C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages`) if 
   you have it installed already
3. reupload `psutil`now using `pip install psutil`

. It helped me and if you have a permission error, try opening cmd as administrator.

Comment: Or windows powershell. Worked fine.

Comment: For those who, like me, didn't know what was meant by "delete psutil", it means literally just "rm -rf" the directory. After that, you're free to install it with pip.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem trust me this works 100%. I am using VS Code you just have to install it with pip normally but sometimes it doesn't add it to your working directories (`venv\lib\site-packages\`) folder your editor is using. So just copy and paste it there from here `C:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue as below:
It seems, every time i was trying to upgrade psutil using "pip install psutil" it just showing the requirement is satisfied and showing 5.7.2.

1. Go to the folder where Python is install and psutil is available e.g.
   "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages"
2. find all psutil related filesand rename them to something else e.g.
   Old__psutil
   Old_psutil-5.7.2.dist-info
3. Run "pip install psutil" from bash or command line
4. It updated for me to 5.8.0

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inconsistencies can happen if you have multiple versions of windows installed on your system. Check for the default python directory path and make sure 'psutils' is updated in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and solved it by **specifying the exact (virtual environment / global) `pip` you are using**. In my case (using a virtual environment), after executed `pip` by using the absolute path, I installed `psutil` successfully.

[image: psutil issue]

Answer (score 0):

These two commands typed in the SSH shell worked for me.  The apt install is what was showing me the error mentioned.

```
sudo apt install pip
python3 -m pip install psutil
```

Result:
python3 -m pip install psutil
Collecting psutil
Downloading psutil-5.9.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (284 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 284 kB 2.0 MB/s
Installing collected packages: psutil
Successfully installed psutil-5.9.1

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, but not quite exactly the same circumstances. I am writing this for any people that have the same problem as I did.

I was running `sudo python script.py` (sudo was needed since I wanted to alter cpu frequencies) but `Error : No module named 'psutil'` appeared. I checked my python version with

`python --version`

and it was 3.8, but when I checked my version with

`sudo python --version`

it was running version 2.7. Once I ran

`sudo python3 script.py`

it ran smoothly. Of course I had already verified I had the newest pip installed + psutil library installed on python3. Basically, make sure you are running the correct python version and you have all libraries/package managers up to date, hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. I had multiple version of python in my ubuntu system.

```
$ sudo apt install python3.6-dev
```