# Visual studio says psutil module not found even though it's installed

Tags: python, pip, psutil

I've got a problem with using psutil in python project. Psutil is installed, but visual studio still says it's not found. Any ideas why it's not working? I'm using Win 10 and Visual Studio 16.8.1 and python 3.9

[image]

[image]

Edit: I tried all of these:

[image]

Edit 2:

I uninstalled psutil and tried to install it again:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\qmotusotus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\qmotusotus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9gi_5la8\\psutil\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\qmotusotus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9gi_5la8\\psutil\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\qmotusotus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gckzeuh8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\qmotusotus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\psutil'
         cwd: C:\Users\qmotusotus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9gi_5la8\psutil\
    Complete output (47 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_memleaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_testutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psutil\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil\arch
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil\arch\windows
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=573 -DPSUTIL_WINDOWS=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x01000 -D_AVAIL_WINVER_=0x01000 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 -Ic:\users\qmotusotus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\qmotusotus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt /Tcpsutil/_psutil_common.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\psutil/_psutil_common.obj
    _psutil_common.c
    c:\users\qmotusotus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\pyconfig.h(201): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
    VisualStudio is not installed; get it from http://www.visualstudio.com/en-au/news/vs2015-preview-vs
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\qmotusotus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\qmotusotus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9gi_5la8\\psutil\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\qmotusotus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9gi_5la8\\psutil\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\qmotusotus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gckzeuh8\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\qmotusotus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\psutil' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: "Installed" does't say a lot .. Was it installed for same interpreter or distribution? With or without virtual environments, with --user flag  ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean

Comment: Unclear what interpreter your IDE is set to use (are you using a virtualenv?). Also curious why you are importing pip

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot the import pip in there. Had trouble before and had to test it. Was able to install pip after upgrading to newest version of python (3.9)

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run `python your_script.py` from CMD?

Comment: According to the pypi page here: https://pypi.org/project/psutil/#files .. There are no python3.9 wheels available. Thus, when you try to install psutil which compiles native code at install time (because its not a wheel), the psutil installation fails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer** 
In Windows command prompt enter:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then write:

```
python -m pip install psutil
```

and just in case type:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade psutil
```

**References and Additional Links:** 
[Error : No module named 'psutil'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316358/error-no-module-named-psutil)

Comment: Tried all of those but no difference

Comment: or delete the package from your site-packages python folder

Comment: and then reinstall the package

Comment: Don't run it with admin privileges

Comment: Hmm i uninstalled psutil and tried to install it again. I got this error:  VisualStudio is not installed; get it from http://www.visualstudio.com/en-au/news/vs2015-preview-vs
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Comment: That's strange. When you use command prompt are you using it as administrator or as a user

Comment: I also repaired visual studio and build tools just in case -> no effect

Comment: If you have time, can you fully uninstall VS2019, and then reinstall it. A fresh install may solve the import errors.